# DOTNET CORE JWT Error converting value \"Username\" to type 'jwt_example.Model.LoginModel ERROR

Tags: api, .net-core, jwt

I'm trying to write an API with dotnet core 3.1 + JWT.
I created LoginModel and authController when I try to get a token
postman says to me:

```
 "Error converting value \"Username\" to type 'jwt_example.Model.LoginModel"
```

That is my authController code :

```
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
 {

    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManger;

    public AuthController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManger)
    {
        this.userManger = userManger;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
    {
         var user = await userManger.FindByNameAsync((model.Username).ToString());
        //var user =  await 
        
        if (user != null && await userManger.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };

            var signinKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ŞanlıFenerbahçe."));


            JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken
        (
            issuer: "https://localhost:5001",
            audience: "https://localhost:5001",
            claims: claims,
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(signinKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)
        );

            return Ok(new
            {
                token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                expiration = token.ValidTo
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(new
            {
                message = "Kullanıcı adı veya şifre hatalı!"
            });
        }
    }


}
```

And, that is loginModel.cs:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Kullanıcı adı boş geçilemez.")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Parola boş geçilemez.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```